# Create a new multidimensional array from a existing array (php)

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to create a array from another one that already exists, making a new data structure.

At this point I already have the new array

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x0gn-1ikz

The problem is:

At the new array in the 10:00:00 - 15:00:00 should apear 3 records:

```
Array
(
    [10:00:00 - 15:00:00] => Array
        (
            [2014-08-03] => Jonh
            [2014-08-04] => Jonh
            [2014-08-04] => Lewis
        )
```

But as you can see in the fidle only two of the apear, I belive this is a simple trick, but had blowed my head, the "problem" is in the records that have a date ans time equal....

Can I have some help please?

Comment: You have to rethink your desired structure. It's impossible to use the same key for two values in PHP arrays.

Comment: What you actually want to achieve?

Comment: That is a real problem..... I'ts a newbie error.... I'll update de fidle with the final result that I want to achive in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change 114th line of your code to this:

```
$final[$time][$value[2]][] = $value[1];
```

to create array of names. `print_r($final)` will then print:

```
Array
(
    [10:00:00 - 15:00:00] => Array
        (
            [2014-08-03] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Jonh
                )

            [2014-08-04] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Jonh
                    [1] => Lewis
                )

        )
```

Is that what you want?

Let's say array shown above is $table_array. Now to write name in column you use something like:

```
echo '<td>'.$table_array['10:00:00 - 15:00:00']['04-08-2014'].'</td>';
```

instead, you would write something like:

```
$names = '';
foreach ($table_array['10:00:00 - 15:00:00']['04-08-2014'] as $name)
    $names .= $name . ', ';
$names = rtrim($names, ', ');
echo '<td>'.$names.'</td>';
```

If you do it different way then please post your code so I know how to help you

Comment: I belive that is the solution, in the very end I will need to populate a table with that array, to achive this result http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z82w-gupe

Comment: But why do you need two rows with hour "10:00:00 - 15:00:00"? Can't you just put "Lewis" in first row?

Comment: I need two rows cause I need to have each record in one cell, as I have 2 records in the same time(row) I prefer to repeat the rows than to repeat the columns.

Comment: I honestly apreciate your effort, the way you posted generates the two names in the same cell, wuith a comma(,). Is very importante to me placing each name in a diferent cell, as I show in the fidle of result phpfiddle.org/main/code/z82w-gupe, because after that I'll manege to make database changes inline in the table, and for that I must have each record in a individual cell.

Comment: I don't think you must have each record in an individual cell. If `$names` contains names from cell, you can do something like `$separated_names = explode(', ', $names);` and then loop through all elements (separated names) so you can make database changes for every name

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is duplicate key. For an instance, you try to push both `jonh` and `lewis` at the index of `[10:00:00 - 15:00:00][2014-08-03]` You need another array there, so the structure will be a 3D array.

One plausible structure looks like,

```
Array
(
    [10:00:00 - 15:00:00] => Array
        (
            [2014-08-03] => Array 
                (
                  [0] => Jonh
                )
            [2014-08-04] => Array
                (
                  [0] => Lewis
                  [1] => Jonh
                 )
        )
```

Comment: Tks so much for the help, but I belive that the foreach is necessary, to create a null record, because when I went to populate the table I need the null values to fill the cells, other wise the data will be placed out of order.... I belive.... In the very end I need to achive this... with php off course phpfiddle.org/main/code/z82w-gupe